# Can't Get my Calendar to display correctly in ASP.NET web form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two drop down list and a calendar control in my webform. When I click on my calendar values. It should select the right values and place the values in my dropdown list, but nothing is showing in my drop down lists after i selected them. The ID values are correctly named. The even handler is wired. I'm confused what's going on.  Here is the code I'm using to link them together.

```
 protected void clnArrival_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlMonth.SelectedValue = clnArrival.SelectedDate.Month.ToString();
    ddlDay.SelectedValue = clnArrival.SelectedDate.Day.ToString();

}
```

here my aspx code

```
  <asp:Calendar ID="clnArrival" runat="server" Visible="true"       
  OnSelectionChanged="clnArrival_SelectionChanged">
         <TodayDayStyle BackColor="Blue" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"  
         />
         <TitleStyle BackColor="Blue" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <NextPrevStyle ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:Calendar>
```

### Edit

*This information was taking from an answer that should have been an edit*

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server" Height="18px" Width="150px">
 </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDay" runat="server" Width="173px">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Did you try using break points? What happens, any error? does it reach the function in the first place?

Comment: I got one of them to work correctly. The date one. It required me to actually load in list items in my dropdown box. The month dropdown box still doesn't work. I tried to fill in my dropdown box with list items with the value of the name of the months. No luck.

Comment: I got it to work now. Both of them. The advice to do breakpoints helped. Once I realize that the Month property was being used as a numerical value instead of a string. I replaced all the list items as value = "1" for janurary  etc and it worked. Thanks TheUknown.

Comment: no problem! debugger always comes to the rescue :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server" Height="18px"   
     Width="150px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">January</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">February</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">March</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">April</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5">May</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="6">June</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="7">July</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="8">August</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="9">September</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="10">October</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="11">November</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="12">December</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDay" runat="server" Width="173px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

 protected void clnArrival_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlMonth.SelectedValue = clnArrival.SelectedDate.Month.ToString();
    ddlDay.SelectedValue = clnArrival.SelectedDate.Day.ToString();

}
```

This code should work, now the two droplists will display the proper month and date, just make sure your aspx value property for the droplists are correct.